# How can I iterate and call a function that updates every individual elements of a React state hash?

Tags: reactjs

My React App has a state called googleAccounts which is initially empty:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
      value: '',
      googleAccounts: {}
    };
  },
```

I have a simple search bar. When a search is performed, the server communicates with Google's API to get a list of accounts for that search, then `googleAccounts` is populated with accounts. This works wonderfully and the accounts are displayed below the search bar as search results.

```
searchGoogleAccounts(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Client.getGoogleAccounts(this.state.value, (accounts) => {
      this.setState({googleAccounts: accounts});
    });
  },
```

Then I want to take each account and send it to the Atlassian API to see if the account exists in the Atlassian database. I made a function that takes the account name and if there is an Atlassian account for that name it returns that account in JSON. This function also works fine.

I'm just not sure how I should use this function to properly interact with the DOM. If there is an Atlassian account I want to display a checkmark. If there is not an account I want to display a button to make the Atlassian account. And while it's waiting for a response from the Atlassian API I want to display a loading icon.

I tried adding an `atlassian` property to each of the `googleAccounts`. The problem with this approach was that I had to update the entire `googleAccounts` each time I grabbed an `atlassian` account. So separate calls would update `googleAccounts` at the same time and overwrite each other's changes. I thought about altering the DOM directly within the function but I read that this is considered insecure. I am not sure what my best option is and any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look into Redux since you're managing the state of many items and a reducer might help.

Comment: Please show how you were using `setState` to update the `atlassian` property. Leaving out details like this makes it harder to know what you were doing wrong. I posted an answer but I'm assuming the issue you ran into. If it's wrong, you should show what you've already tried to help narrow down the problem, though even if it's right it will be informative to anyone else finding this question to see the original attempt in contrast to the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an updater function to `setState` instead.

```js
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {
    googleAccounts: {
      ...prevState.googleAccounts,
      [someGoogleAcctId]: {
        ...prevState.googleAccounts[someGoogleAcctId],
        atlassian: resultOfAPICall
      }
    }
  };
});
```

This way you aren't accessing `this.state` in multiple API callbacks, and instead you're always receiving the currently up-to-date state before altering it. Your callbacks were probably overwriting each other's changes because they were starting from the same original state snapshot, instead of taking the existing state changes into account (which you can't do if you're not using the updater functions, since you don't have access to the intermediate states).